# Any way to extract a variable name from a string value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three lists. Depending on user interaction, these list may either be available or unavailable to the user, and the way I set it up was to keep track of both the list names and states through a fourth list. But I run into trouble when I try to use the string value from my fourth list to access one of my other lists.

That is, I want to add all the strings from the available lists to a master list - how should I go about this?

```
domesticated = ['cow', 'sheep', 'pig']
pets = ['cat', 'dog']
wildlife = ['giraffe', 'lion', 'panda']

masterList = ['domesticated', 'pets', 'wildlife'],  ['off', 'on', 'on']

def currentLists():
    activeList = ''
    for i in range(len(masterList[0])):
        if masterList[1][i] == 'on':
            activeList = activeList + masterList[0][i]
    return activeList
```

Current output:

```
petswildlife
```

Desired output:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'giraffe', 'lion', 'panda']
```

My apologies for any confusion, I'm a complete beginner with Python. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a dict like animals = {"pets":['cat','doc']}; animals["pets"]. And forget about using globals() and locals().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use strings but the variables themselves.  I also changed the script to use `zip`: `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.  You … zip sequences with it.

```
domesticated = ['cow', 'sheep', 'pig']
pets = ['cat', 'dog']
wildlife = ['giraffe', 'lion', 'panda']

masterList = zip([domesticated, pets, wildlife],  ['off', 'on', 'on'])

def currentLists():
    activeList = []
    for e in masterList:
        if e[1] == 'on':
            activeList += e[0]

    return activeList
```

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the three variables `domesticated`, `pets` and `wildlife` with a single `dict`:

```
animals = {'domesticated': ['cow', 'sheep', 'pig'],
           'pets': ['cat', 'dog'],
           'wildlife': ['giraffe', 'lion', 'panda']}
```

then

```
activeList = []  # not ''!
for category, status in zip(*masterList):
    if status == 'on':
        activeList += animals[category]
```

Note the `zip(*masterList)`, which means the same as `zip(masterList[0], masterList[1])`. Using `zip` and two loop variables is the idiomatic way of looping over two lists simultaneously.

For extra Python points, you can use `sum` to append the lists:

```
sum((animals[category] for category, status in zip(*masterList)
                       if status == 'on'),
    [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite [Gandaro's good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453650/210905), retrieving variable by name **is possible**.

There are [vars()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars), [globals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) and [locals()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) functions.
So if you want to fix it straight, you could do that this way:

```
domesticated = ['cow', 'sheep', 'pig']
pets = ['cat', 'dog']
wildlife = ['giraffe', 'lion', 'panda']

masterList = ['domesticated', 'pets', 'wildlife'],  ['off', 'on', 'on']

def currentLists():
    activeList = []
    for i in range(len(masterList[0])):
        if masterList[1][i] == 'on':
            activeList = activeList + globals()[masterList[0][i]]
    return activeList
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the use of `vars`, `globals` or `locals` to novice programmers.